# What are the best ways to strategically rank up?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

are there any good ways to tier up faster I have heard, of the one way in which you hug the edge of a storm and keep healing but it's super boring any other good ways? I am a very skilled player but it seems when you hit a certain rank you get placed with hackers.

Comment: Are these puppet accounts?

Answer (score 0):

like to use Erangel and survive, survival is the most important thing , you would think kills are, that's false , stay alive by any means necessary! but strategically speaking you would play safe and calm until the last about 20 people left and then you would go for the kills , not full blown run and gun but just look for more opportunities, never shoot the enemy unless you know you have a at least 75 percent chance of direct contact or your liable to also get a 3rd party in there and kill you both , try to survive, it' boring but strategically it seems to be the way it works in Player's unknown.

Answer (score -1):

I like to Make use of the map ERANGELl and survive, survival is the most important thing, you would think kills are, that's false, stay alive by any means necessary! Go for headshots and watch out for wide-open running enemies and the 3rd part campers. also, it's so flooded with hackers these days. Goodluck.